# Access Groovy (jenkinsfile) variable inside command-substitution sh block

Tags: curl, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a common jenkinsfile (Jenkins 2.0 pipeline plugin) and I am trying to run a 'nested' curl command inside of a script component:

```
                    def v = version()
                    def envId = environment()
                    def projectId = projectId()
                    def APIKey = xxx
                    sh "curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Octopus-ApiKey: "'$APIKey'" -d '{"ReleaseId":"'$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Octopus-ApiKey: "'$APIKey'" -d '{"version":"'$v'", "ProjectId":"'$projectId'", "Environment-Id":"'$envId'"}' http://xxxxx | grep '"Id":' | head -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '"' -f 2)'", "EnvironmentId":"'$envId'"}' http://xxxxxx"
```

As you can see, I am using command substitution within the curl command to pass the ReleaseId value. Do I need to be using a different way to access the variables such as envId, projectId, and APIKey within the $() command substitution portion of my curl command?

From previous research I am wrapping the values of they JSON keys in the format "'$somevar'" however I am getting standard errors for that not being found.

Thank you

Comment: You need to escape your interpolated `"` with `\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you don't escape the double quotes within the command. For Groovy the string which is passed to the `sh` command ends just before `Content-Type` unless you escape the double quotes with a backslash.

Also you need to escape dollar signs you want to be interpreted by Bash. Groovy's string interpolation uses the same syntax as Bash.

I tried to fix your command. Hopefully I found all the issues:

```
sh "curl -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"X-Octopus-ApiKey: \"'${APIKey}'\" -d '{\"ReleaseId\":\"'\$(curl -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"X-Octopus-ApiKey: \"'${APIKey}'\" -d '{\"version\":\"'${v}'\", \"ProjectId\":\"'${projectId}'\", \"Environment-Id\":\"'${envId}'\"}' http://xxxxx | grep '\"Id\":' | head -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '\"' -f 2)'\", \"EnvironmentId\":\"'${envId}'\"}' http://xxxxxx"
```

By the way, I put the variables from groovy in curly braces. This is not necessary in this case but I consider it a good practice.